# How to make all the bootstrap panel clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want do a bootstrap panel clickable. But not the head clickable. ALL the panel clickable. I'm trying but when I add my div into `<a>` all content is linkable, and I dislike this text blue by links...

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="panel-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="row">
              ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

How can do my bootstrap panel clickable?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Lists for this?

Comment: _"and I dislike this text blue by links"_ - then style it differently!

Answer (score 5):

You could style it, and better if you could add a class for clickable ones so that will not affect others :

```
<div class="panel panel-default clickable-panel" data-href=''>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.clickable-panel a:hover, .clickable-panel a:active {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Or if you don't want to use `a` tag you could add a CSS attribute `cursor` to the class `panel` that have `data-href` attribute that will make it clickable :

```
.panel[data-href]{
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Then add `data-href` that contain the link you want to redirect to, example :

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-href=''>
    ...
</div>
```

Then in your JS code add event :

```
$('body').on('click', '.panel[data-href]', function(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
        window.location.hash = $(this).data('href');
    } else {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
    }
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.panel[data-href]', function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
    window.location.hash = $(this).data('href');
  } else {
    window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
  }
})
```

```css
.panel[data-href]{
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default" data-href='#test'>
  <div class="panel-body">
     Go to test div
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="row">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id='test'>
  TEST DIV
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove all styling of links from your panel :

```css
.panel-default a:link, .panel-default a:hover, .panel-default a:visited, .panel-default a:active {
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="panel-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div class="row">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```